# Magento - using Mage to edit a product?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to integrate some functionality of Magento into my custom CMS to make it easier for my clients to update some of their products.

I already have classes written to retrieve all the data information I need, but I'm trying to figure out how to save changes to a product in the same fashion (IE, attributes such as color, size, packaging).  Is this possible to do through mage?

Right now I essentially construct a class like below, then have various functions to filter products, sessions, and generate thumbnails... but I can't seem to find anything on editing a product.

`Mage::app();

$this->model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');`

Has anyone else tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much hassle, I pieced together some code that works:

```
function setAttribute($pid,$options)
{
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
  $this->model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
  foreach ($options as $k=>$v)
  {
    $this->model->setData($k,$v);
  }
  $this->model->save();
}
```

You pass a product ID and an array of the data you'd like to update for said product.
something like below:

```
$options = array('labels'=>"No",
'sizee_us_gal'=>1.98,
'size_l'=>7.5,
'makes_us_gal'=>7,
'makes_l'=>23,
'timeframe_weeks'=>4,
'composition'=>"grapes",
'packed'=>"case of 2"
);
```

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to first load a specific product.  You can do that by using the load() method and passing in a product id:

```
$this->model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1111);
```

You can then set (modify) your product data like this:

```
$this->model->setName('New Product Name');
$this->model->setPrice(99.99);
$this->model->setShortDescription('New Short Description');
```

Then simply run the save() method to save the product:

```
$this->model->save();
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit any of attributes on the product? IE, I'm selling bottles of wine and would like to change a few custom attributes such as year, ABV, or type (red/white)?

Comment: Yes it is possible to change any attribute in this way. A single exception might be images for the product, as they are a little more convoluted.

Comment: After I've loaded a product, I can retrieve an attribute I need to edit such as "manufacturer" by doing $this->model->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($product).  How do I then set the value after retrieving it?

Comment: @LinuxGnut you can use setData('manufacturer','newData') after you load the product